# How to differentiate areas which are spatially disconnected

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

So, I've done some geoprocessing on a bunch of raster data, and I have a large number of points spread out across a large area. I would like to remove all the data points which are only one or two cells, which is just noise, so that I can more easily identify areas where the data is continuous and relevant.

I'm thinking that the best way to do this is to convert to vector and separate each area which is not connected to another area into its own row, then delete all rows with a small area.

However, I don't know how to separate the data into many rows? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are your points *points* or *cells*? How does your data value relate to the not data values, is it less than, more than, just not NoData?

Comment: Have you looked at [ArcScan cell selection](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/About_cell_selection/000w0000000w000000/)?  If not, and if you have access to ArcScan licensing, then that may be the solution - it is what your question reminded me of immediately.  I think it gets referred to as despeckling too.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, your scenario is outlined in the ArcGIS help, entitled, "[Generalization of classified raster imagery](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//009z0000003p000000)."

As described on the linked page, you can remove single "noisy" cells using [Majority Filter](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#/Majority_Filter/009z00000037000000/). If you decide that larger contiguous groups of pixels are "noisy," use [Region Group](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/009z/009z00000039000000.htm) to form pixel clusters, then [Extract by Attributes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/009z/009z00000029000000.htm) (or one of several other raster selection tools) to select groups meeting the threshold for being significant, and finally [Nibble](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/009z/009z00000038000000.htm) to fill in the resulting holes.